# Can't publish .NET Core Web Application (could not load file or assembly Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to publish my application, but I keep running into the error:

### System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.

I thought maybe there was something wrong with my project, but I ran into the exact same problem following these steps to create a blank template project:

1 - Visual Studio 2015 (update 3 plus patch installed) => File => New => Project => ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) with individual user accounts

2 - Right click project => Publish => Selected my Azure Profile => Click Publish

3 - Publish fails with the above error

Here is my project.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc3-003121"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
```

I've tried to find the missing package in Nuget and I've tried to add it manually to the project.json, neither has worked. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't get a repro on this from anyone else, I reinstalled the OS, Visual Studio, and all the bits on my work station, and now it's working. Still not sure where the underlying problem came from, but it seems to have been a weird state that was entered on my machine sometime around the release of ASP.NET Core 1.0

Answer (score 2):

Really I dont see the ProductModel in the config file.

Can you please try `Install-Package Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel -Pre` via package manager console. or Right-Click the project and select Manage NuGet Package and search for `Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel` and install that.

Then check the package.json, you must have a section `Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel`.

## Update based on comment

Tried the steps below to show.

1. Create a new .Net Core Web Application.
2. Right Click References and select Manage NuGet Package.
3. Search for `Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel` under Browse section. - Note : You need have the pre release option selected.

After installation you will be able to see this.

[image]

Tried to publish to my local drive itself and got published without any issues

[image]

Complete Build Log,

```
1>------ Build started: Project: dotmodelissue, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe build "E:\Thenna\StackOverFlow\dotmodelissue" --configuration Release --no-dependencies
1>  Project dotmodelissue (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
1>  Compiling dotmodelissue for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
1>  Compilation succeeded.
1>      0 Warning(s)
1>      0 Error(s)
1>  Time elapsed 00:00:01.7973890
1>
2>------ Publish started: Project: dotmodelissue, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
Connecting to E:\ddd...
Environment variables:
Path=.\node_modules\.bin;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External;%PATH%;D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Web\External\git
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe publish "E:\Thenna\StackOverFlow\dotmodelissue" --framework netcoreapp1.0 --output "C:\Users\thenna\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\dotmodelissue57" --configuration Release --no-build
Publishing dotmodelissue for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
Configuring the following project for use with IIS: 'C:\Users\thenna\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\dotmodelissue57'
Updating web.config at 'C:\Users\thenna\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\dotmodelissue57\web.config'
Configuring project completed successfully
publish: Published to C:\Users\thenna\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\dotmodelissue57
Published 1/1 projects successfully
Publishing with publish method [FileSystem]
Publishing files to E:\ddd
Executing command ["C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:manifest='C:\Users\thenna\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\dotmodelissue57\SourceManifest.xml' -dest:manifest='C:\Users\thenna\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\obj\dotmodelissue57\DestinationManifest.xml' -verb:sync -retryAttempts:20 -disablerule:BackupRule]
Total changes: 204 (125 added, 79 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 5540847 bytes copied)

Web App was published successfully file:///E:/ddd

========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

## Publish to Azure

[image]

Comment: Apologies, I had removed it from my project.json because it didn't work and I forgot to put it back in. I'm still getting the same error with the following line in my project.json:     "Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel": "1.0.0-rc3-003121"   (Updated main post)

Comment: Does `Microsoft.DotNet.ProjectModel` is showing in the installed section when you check Manage NuGet Package? If it is, just click on uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: The rc3 version of ProjectModel that I just installed showed up in the installed section - I tried uninstalling and reinstalling as you suggest and I'm still getting the same error. The error seems to be looking for a version 1.0.0.0 - but all I can find are the release candidate packages. Am I missing a piece of the .NET Core SDK?

Comment: Updated existing comment.. please check.

Comment: Thank you for the update, however, I'm still receiving the issue following the same steps. The only difference is the publishing - I can run the program on localhost just fine but it's when I try to publish it to Azure that I run into the issue. I should have been more clear in my question. Could this be an issue with IIS or the Azure profile?

Comment: Tried that too. It deployed successfully without any issues. If possible can you share your code, will check and resolve and send over. OR try to create a new project and check it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error when publishing to Azure. What helped for me was to change the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools to 1.0.0-preview1-final in the project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
  "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
},
```

I must say I don't know why this works, so any insights are welcome